# Is there a standard way to create Atom-format podcasts?

Tags: atom-feed, podcast

Searching for "atom podcast" finds me podcasts about atoms, which I'm sure are fascinating but are not what I'm looking for. I've built an RSS feed for a podcast, but I'd like to replace it with Atom, which seems to be better defined and more capable of including arbitrary HTML content.

Comment: Since Google led me here on the same search, I just want to suggest that this is not a good idea for publishers. I'm entirely onboard with Atom being a cleaner feed format, but in practical terms, iTunes' RSS-flavoured spec is well-entrenched among podcast client libraries and apps beyond iTunes and even Apple's OSs. An Atom feed risks being incompatible with some of them. A lot of feed parsing libraries just provide an array of links and don't do anything intelligent with the link type, so the official enclosure may be ignored. /rant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [enclosure](http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/#link) `link` (or multiple) in your `entry` subtree(s).

[An overview of the Atom 1.0 Syndication Format](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-atom10/index.html#N100EB) has a nice side-by-side example of an RSS and Atom podcast feed.

Comment: example:

<link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod.watchitlater/output/Presentation%20Video.mov.mp4" type="video/mp4" rel="enclosure"/>

Comment: Seems IBM has changed their website and the overview link is broken. Here is a wayback machine link to what I presume was the intended content: https://web.archive.org/web/20140228123540/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-atom10/index.html

Also...thanks IBM...nice jo